# Regular expression to split between pipes except in brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text line:

```
|random|[abc|www.abc.org]|1024|
```

I would like to split these into 3 parts with a regular expression

```
random
[abc|www.abc.org]
1024
```

Currently the following result is achieved with expression \|

```
random
[abc
www.abc.org]
1024
```

My problem is that I cannot exclude the pipe symbol in the middle column surrounded by the brackets [].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use `split`, you can use the regex

```
\|(?=$|[^]]+\||\[[^]]+\]\|)
```

https://regex101.com/r/7OxmiY/1

It will match a pipe, then lookahead for either:

`$`, the end of the string, so that the final `|` is split on, or

`[^]]+\|`, non-`]` characters until a pipe is reached, ensuring that pipes inside `[]`s will not be split upon, or

`\[[^]]+\]\|` - Same as above, except with literal `[` and `]`s surrounding the pattern

In Java:

```
String input = "|random|[abc|www.abc.org]|[test]|1024|";
String[] output = input.split("\\|(?=$|[^]]+\\|)");
```

Comment: Works great so far, but when I have a line like this:
"|random|[abc|www.abc.org]|[test]|1024|".split("\\|(?=$|[^]]+\\|)")
it does not work, any suggestions?

Comment: See edit, add alternation for `[` and `]` surrounding the pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can use follow code:

```
final String regex = "(?<=|)\\[?[\\w.]+\\|?[\\w.]+\\]?(?=|)";
final String string = "|random|[abc|www.abc.org]|[test]|1024|";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
Full match: random
Full match: [abc|www.abc.org]
Full match: [test]
Full match: 1024
```

See here at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/Fcb3Wx/1